# Python: Sort a list so that 5.10 is after 5.9

Tags: python, sorting, sections

how would you sort a list of numbers like 5.1, 5.2, 5.3,... 5.10,5.11 in a way that doesn't put 5.10 and 5.11 after 5.1 in Python. I basically want python to realize that I don't actually mean 5.10 but section 5, subsection 10.

Comment: but 5.10 == 5.1 as float. So treat elements as strings from the start. IF you can't do that there's no way to differentiate 5.1 from 5.10

Answer (score 5):

You could treat it in the same way as a version number, for example:

```
>>> from distutils.version import LooseVersion

>>> a = ["5.1", "5.10", "5.11", "5.2"]

>>> sorted(a, key=LooseVersion)
['5.1', '5.2', '5.10', '5.11']
```

The assumption here is that you have the data in the form of strings.  (It is not meaningful to distinguish e.g. 5.1 and 5.10 as floats.)

Comment: I don't think we can answer better than that.

Answer (score 2):

There's a library called [**`natsort`**](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) which does exactly that:

```
from natsort import natsorted
a = ["5.1", "5.10", "5.11", "5.2"]
print(natsorted(a))
# ['5.1', '5.2', '5.10', '5.11']
```

Comment: which makes me realize that the question is a duplicate.

Comment: yes, I thought that the problem was different. And the other answer proposes something not in the original question answers too. Merge could be an option but the input is too different.